# Export image as pdf, which is PDF/A valid

Tags: export, color, pdf-format, fonts, compatibility

Assume following plot in Mathematica (version 11.2):

```
Plot[
 {
  Exp[-x] Sin[10 x],
  Exp[-3 x] Sin[25 x]
  },
 {x, 0, 5},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"1", "2"}, {0.7, 0.7}]
 ]
```

This produces the following output:

[image: example plot]

I want to include this image in my document, which is required to be [PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) valid (document's source is in *LaTeX* and I have no problem producing a valid PDF/A valid document without the image from *Mathematica*) and the images (included via the LaTeX *includegraphics* command) are recommended to be in the pdf format.

To include it in the document, I export the plot via context menu *Save graphics as ...* -> choose PDF extension, or via the  *Export* command

```
Export["plot.pdf", %]
```

However, the final PDF document can be PDF/A valid only if its source is PDF/A valid as well as all included pdf images.
Is it possible to export the plot from *Mathematica* as pdf so it is PDF/A-2U valid? The exported pdf with **default** settings is **not** pdf/a valid, e.g. the validator [veraPDF](http://verapdf.org/) outputs the following errors:

[image: veraPDF_report]

Including not PDF/A file into the main document ruins the PDF/A validity of the whole document.

Or is it possible to change **Plot** options - i.e. change fonts, colors, so the **Export** command will produce pdf/a valid image?

What am I missing? Or perhaps is there an easier way?
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: It might be easier to convert the PDF to a compliant one using other tools. PDF24 for example seems to be able to save the PDF from Mathematica as PDF/A-1b compliant, without breaking anything. However, I haven't got this to work for PDF/A-2U yet